# How to refer to a enum member when there is a local variable exists with the same name as the enum member?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum color {b,g,i,k};

void main()
{
   int b=100; //line 7
   enum color out=b; //line 8
   printf("%d\n",out);
}
```

In `line 8` the `b` which i am referring to is `color.b` not the one which declared at `line 7` .In `C++` i can refer `b from color` as `color::b`, in `C` How do i do this?

Comment: It's not really possible in C, as enumerations are really nothing more than fancy *global* symbolic numeric integer constants.

Comment: @user3386109 Noted. thanks for the input

Comment: not possible with enum but check my answer if you want to emulate C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a comment already mentioned, enumerations are part of the global scope. Usually, a prefix is used to distinguish them, for example:

```c
enum color {
    cB, cG, cI, cK
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the following way:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

struct color_s {
    int b,g,i,k;
} const color = {0,1,2,3};

void main()
{
   int b=100; //line 7
   int out = color.b; //line 8
   printf("%d\n",out);
}
```